# AdaptiveGridView XAML Control Image source

Tags: xaml, uwp, windows-community-toolkit

How can i make the `AdaptiveGridView` view images from the web?
I only can let it view images that are already in my assets folder and when i try to set the source to be a link to an image, it just displays a white image and now download that image.

Comment: I will save you some time before the Big guys here decide to close the question because it is incomplete or missing info. If you want answers, Show it in question what you tried ( Snippets from your code ) and what did you search for on SO before posting this question.

Answer (score 1):

To show images form the web, we can take advantage of [**Image**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.aspx) control. [**Image.Source**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.source.aspx) supports **http:** or **https:** schemes and while setting the source to a URI value that can't be resolved to a valid image source file  or decoding failures, it will fire an [**ImageFailed**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imagefailed.aspx) event. We can use this event to deal with potential errors. For more info, please see **Remarks** in [Image.ImageFailed event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image.imagefailed.aspx).

Besides, in [AdaptiveGridView Sample Page](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.SampleApp/SamplePages/AdaptiveGridView), it uses local assets for demonstration. We can easily change `AdaptiveGridViewControl.ItemsSource` like following to use online images.

```
AdaptiveGridViewControl.ItemsSource = await new Data.PhotosDataSource().GetItemsAsync(true);
```

Also, as you are using UWP Community Toolkit, you can use [ImageEx XAML Control](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp-community-toolkit/controls/imageex.htm) instead of `Image` control. This control downloads images asynchronously, while showing a loading indicator. Source images are then stored in the application’s local cache to preserve resources and load time. ImageEx also extends the default `Image` Platform control to improve performance through caching. You can also use a placeholder image that will be displayed will loading the main image.